# Set default value on select of page layout in cms_page_form.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, cms

I would like to set a default value for the select on the page layout when creating a new cms page in Magento 2. The file I'd like to make an extension for is cms_page_form.xml under module-cms > view > ui_component. Unfortunately  `<item name="default" xsi:type="string">2</item>` to set the second item in the list as default, isn't working. Any thoughts on how to do this in XML?

```
<field name="page_layout">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\PageLayout</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Layout</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">page_layout</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You was very close! you can use the following snippet.

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="string">Value in select box goes here</item>
```

And full snippet here

```
        <field name="page_layout">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\PageLayout</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Layout</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">page_layout</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

You can find the value of the select box by inspecting it in the browser.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Create the UI Component XML file

Create `[Your_Namespace]/[Your_Module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml`. Add `<module name="Magento_Cms"/>` to the module's `<sequence/>` in `module.xml`.

#### 2. Add the following

Replace `[1column]` without any layout ID.

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="design">
        <field name="page_layout">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">[1column]</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```